# process update in classic asp for kendo UI

Tags: asp-classic, kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui grid with html and call classic asp
my kendo datasource is like below.
I'm able to list the data using asp, however, I don't know how to do the update in asp.
how the model gets passed into the asp page?

```
var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
                {
                    transport:
                    {
                        read: {
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "defaultAction.asp?Action=List"
                        },
                        update: {
                                url: "defaultAction.asp?Action=Update",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "POST"
                            },
                        parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    batch: true,
                    pageSize: 4,
                     schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "ID",
                                fields: {
                                    ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    Email: { type: "string" },

                                }
                            }
                        }

                })
```

Comment: Inspect your javascript code in the browser to see what it's doing

Answer (score 0):

How to bind Kendo DataSource to a ASP.NET Webforms page and use its code behind methods to perform CRUD is covered in the following example on a [public GitHub repository](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/tree/master/grid-page-methods-crud).

Comment: This is tagged as a Classic ASP question